# supervisord always returns exit status 127 at WebFaction

Tags: python, celery, supervisord, webfaction

I keep getting the following errors from supervisord at webFaction when tailing the log:

```
INFO exited: my_app (exit status 127; not expected)
INFO gave up: my_app entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Here's my supervisord.conf:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/home/btaylordesign/tmp/supervisord.sock

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory=supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///home/btaylordesign/tmp/supervisord.sock

[supervisord]
logfile=/home/btaylordesign/tmp/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB
logfile_backups=5
loglevel=info
nodaemon=false
pidfile=/home/btaylordesign/tmp/supervisord.pid supervisord.pid

[program:my_app]
directory=/home/btaylordesign/webapps/my_app/my_app
command=celery worker -A my_app --concurrency=3 --loglevel=debug
```

I'm starting supervisord from the same directory as supervisord.conf:

```
$ supervisord -c ./supervisord.conf
```

but I can't seem to find the right combination of settings. I need to be able to do three things:

1. Start my celery workers in the background and keep them running.
2. Stop the celery workers when I deploy code.
3. Restart the celery workers when the deploy is complete.

But, I can't do any of that until I resolve the error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Exit code 127 means "command not found":

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Try passing the full path to the `celery` command:

```
command=/home/something/bin/celery worker -A my_app --concurrency=3 --loglevel=debug
```

Also, try setting the `redirect_stderr` and `stdout_logfile` options in your `[program:x]` section to capture the error message and make debugging easier.

Comment: Setting the full path to celery returned the same error when tailing the log. I will try setting the `redirect_stderr` and `stdout_logfile`

Comment: You were correct. I didn't notice a typo in my execution path to celery. Thank you so very, very much for the help.

Comment: No problem :) Happy supervising.